# Fetching twitter data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My requirement is to download followers for a twitter handle. Details I would like to be  downloaded are follower's twitter handle, name, their location, description, account create at.
I have written a python script which I am using to download the followers twitter handle and storing the data in a text file. As I am fairly new to python I am not able to enable this script to fetch all the additional details which I need. Also I would need this data in a excel sheet if possible. Also this script is taking too much time to import the data. The account for which I need the followers have more than 80K followers and my script is taking an hour to fetch around 2k followers.

Here is the script which I am using :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

import tweepy

import time

# == OAuth Authentication ==
consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxx"

consumer_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

access_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

access_token_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

list=open('twtfollow.txt','w')

user = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name='xxxxxxxxxxxx').items()

while True:

    try:

        u=next(user)

        list.write(u.screen_name +' \n')

    except:

        time.sleep(100)

        print('Timeout')

list.close()
```

Comment: why do you do: `list=open('twtfollow.txt','w')`. Are you aware that's overriding `list`? What exceptions are you trying to handle? All the things? Why not handle just the one you care about. Why the time.sleep(100)? Is that important? Instead of `u=next(user)` why not `for u in user:`? Why not use pythons `csv` library to export the results to resolve the excel problem.

Comment: There are API limits and request limits.  Check out: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/rate-limits